# Traverse a hierarchy of objects upwards to find first ancestor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I got many Meeting objects.

Each Meeting object got the following attributes:

```
 - id
 - meeting_id
 - title
```

The user can build a hierarchy of Meeting objects connected through the meeting_id attribute.
I am looking for a way to find the top ancestor of any given Meeting object. So basically I need to find a way to traverse upwards until I find the first Meeting object in a hierarchy.

It is important that the method support an infiniate number of children.

```
This is my attempt. It only supports tree levels :/

def find_parent
if self.meeting_id
  meeting = Meeting.find self.meeting_id
  if meeting.meeting_id
    meeting2 = Meeting.find meeting.meeting_id
    meeting2.id
    if meeting2.meeting_id
      meeting3 = Meeting.find meeting2.meeting_id
      if meeting3.meeting_id
        meeting4 = Meeting.find meeting3.meeting_id
        meeting4.id
      else
        meeting3.id
      end
    else
      meeting2.id
    end
  else
    meeting.id
  end
else
  self.id
end
```

end

Comment: Seems like a simple loop would suffice, or something recursive--what's the stumbling point?

Comment: Problem is to make it support infinite amount of levels and not hard code it. Works otherwise.

Comment: Understood; I'm saying why wouldn't a loop/recursive function work?

Comment: Yes absolutely, but to be honest I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good gem for this [acts as tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree)

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree order: "name"
end
```

You can find, `root`, 'ancestors', 'siblings'

Note: It uses `parent_id` (In your case it is `meeting_id` which i think must be configurable.)

For `Recursive` you can try following

```
def find_parent meeting
  return meeting unless meeting.meeting_id
  meeting = Meeting.find meeting.meeting_id
  find_parent meeting
end
```

Comment: I tried the gem but it is 13 years old and I found no way to use meeting_id instead of parent_id. But your recursive code worked perfectly fine! Thank you!